# Unable to create new project in Eclipse

Tags: metadata, eclipse, force.com-ide

I have installed latest Force.com IDE in eclipse in my local system. I am unable to create a new project. I am able to enter username, password under force.com project, then when clicking on NEXT button is doing nothing. No error message, No warning symbols. I tried to uninstall IDE plugin and installing it by following [These](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_install.htm) steps. Can anyone tell me what to do to fix this. I did checked eclipse Community forum and there is [This](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1096177/) thread where a lot of people complained about same issue but No one shared any solutions. I need to push the code to git once I am able to get this fixed. Please help. Thank you. [image]

Comment: Have you tried [resetting your security token](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_security_token.htm&type=5) and entering that as well? Also, while it should work, the Eclipse plug-in will soon be deprecrated in favor of the [sfdx CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) and [VS Code extensions](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/) . The CLI alone will let you extract metadata, which you could then push to git.

Comment: Yes @ThomasTaylor I tried resetting the security token. Yes, I am well aware that SFDX CLI is going to take over all other tools soon. But, In order to push the current configuration to git, I must use Eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse uses the Metadata API. sfdx does as well, and can convert from the sfdx project directory format to the metadata src format, as well as extract a ZIP that's in that format. If what you need is to extract metadata in src/ format to then push to git, you don't need Eclipse. If building the `package.xml` is the sticking point, try [this VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator) or Ben Edwards's [Package Builder app](https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com).

Comment: I understand what you are saying @ThomasTaylor 
But for this client/production, I can not use Visual Studio Code. If I have to, I need permission which I am going to get a denial. I should use Eclipse which is not working/exporting project.

Comment: Alright. I have deleted all eclipse files IDE files and installed  Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) Now I am able to pull our prod to local. Thank you very much.